# Pinterest authentication not showing all the permissions

Tags: pinterest, pinterest-api

Why do the Pinterest API permissions not display correctly when I attempt to authenticate while already logged in? It's only after I log out and then log in again that I see all the requested permissions. How can I ensure that the permissions are displayed correctly on the authentication screen while logged in?"[Already login in Pinterest before authenticating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJgYT.png)[Login during authentication process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw0jG.png)

I want Pinterest authentication to show all the permission scop while i already login in Pinterest account.